# ibmcloud health check is never passed

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, travis-ci, cloud-foundry

I have a spring boot 2.0 application:

my defaults manifest.yml

```
defaults: &defaults
  buildpack: java_buildpack
  memory: 1024MB
  instances: 2
  health-check-type: http
  health-check-http-endpoint: /health
  timeout: 180
```

sometimes my push failed because of health check is never passed

and TIP that you should use $PORT variable

How can I solve that issue?

Comment: [CELL/0] ERR Failed to make HTTP request to '/health' on port 8080: connection refused
[CELL/0] ERR Timed out after 3m0s: health check never passed. Typical log for that service

Comment: What is your app doing during the 3 mins where the health check is waiting for it to start? It would be good to look and see if your app is hanging while it's attempting to start up, or if it appears to be started but the platform isn't detecting it. I'd suggest running `cf logs` in a separate terminal window while you `cf push` to capture all logs from your app as it starts up, maybe even increase the log level in your app so you can see more details about what it's doing, especially if it gets hung.